# OrientDB 3.0.4 Console EMBEDDEDLIST CREATE VERTEX

Tags: console, orientdb, embeddedlist

It appears that console application in OrientDB 3.0.4 is not backward compatible with OrientDB 3.0.2 for creating Vertex having EMBEDDEDLIST.

Following Query fails in OrientDB 3.0.4 console:

```
 CREATE VERTEX Profile SET name = "John", phone = [{ "@type":"d", "number" : "212" }]
```

How can I resolve the issue?
What are the changes for v3.0.4 and where can I find updated documentation?

---

### OrientDB console v.3.0.2 - Veloce (build e47e693f1470a7a642461be26983d4eca70777fd, branch develop)

```
    OrientDB console v.3.0.2 - Veloce (build e47e693f1470a7a642461be26983d4eca70777fd, branch develop) https://www.orientdb.com
    Type 'help' to display all the supported commands.
    orientdb> create database remote:localhost/mydb root orientdb

    Creating database [remote:localhost/mydb] using the storage type [PLOCAL]...
    Database created successfully.

    Current database is: remote:localhost/mydb
    orientdb {db=mydb}> create class Phone EXTENDS V

    Class created successfully.

    orientdb {db=mydb}> create property Phone.number String

    Property created successfully.

    orientdb {db=mydb}> create class Profile EXTENDS V

    Class created successfully.

    orientdb {db=mydb}> create property Profile.name String

    Property created successfully.

    orientdb {db=mydb}> create property Profile.phone embeddedList Phone

    Property created successfully.

    orientdb {db=mydb}> CREATE VERTEX Profile SET name = "John", phone = [{ "@type":"d", "number" : "212" }]

    Created vertex '[Profile#33:0{name:John,phone:[1]} v1]' in 0.023000 sec(s).

-------
```

---

### OrientDB console v.3.0.4 - Veloce (build 4578b51f72a55feaa0852bc8ddd52929011d956c, branch 3.0.x)

```
    OrientDB console v.3.0.4 - Veloce (build 4578b51f72a55feaa0852bc8ddd52929011d956c, branch 3.0.x) https://www.orientdb.com
    Type 'help' to display all the supported commands.
    orientdb> create database remote:localhost/mydb root orientdb

    Creating database [remote:localhost/mydb] using the storage type [PLOCAL]...
    Database created successfully.

    Current database is: remote:localhost/mydb

    orientdb {db=mydb}> create class Phone EXTENDS V

    Class created successfully.

    orientdb {db=mydb}> create property Phone.number String

    Property created successfully.

    orientdb {db=mydb}> create class Profile EXTENDS V

    Class created successfully.

    orientdb {db=mydb}> create property Profile.name String

    Property created successfully.

    orientdb {db=mydb}> create property Profile.phone embeddedList Phone

    Property created successfully.

    orientdb {db=mydb}> CREATE VERTEX Profile SET name = "John", phone = [{ "@type":"d", "number" : "212" }]

    Error: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.sql.OCommandSQLParsingException: Error parsing query:
    create VERTEX Profile SET name = "John", phone = [{ "@type":"d", "number" : "212" }
                                                     ^
    Encountered " "[" "[ "" at line 1, column 50.
    Was expecting one of:
         ...
         ...
         ...
        "{" ...
         ...
         ...
         ...
        "{" ...
        "{" ...
         ...
         ...
         ...
        "{" ...
        "{" ...
        "{" ...
         ...
         ...
         ...
        "{" ...
        "{" ...
         ...
         ...
         ...
        "{" ...
        "{" ...
         ...
         ...
         ...
        "{" ...
        "{" ...
        "{" ...

        DB name="mydb"
        Error Code="1"
        DB name="mydb"

    !Unrecognized command: ']'
    orientdb {db=mydb}>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you've declared your property as "**Phone**" and then you're trying to create your vertex using the name "**phone**" in lowercase which doesn't match the schema.
Also there's no need to use square brackets so instead of that last query, try using:

```
CREATE VERTEX Profile SET name = "John", Phone = { "@type":"d", "number" : "212"}
```

Comment: dgiannotti, Note that the property name is 'phone' and not 'Phone" and the "Phone" is the type of property in the Profile when created using following:
<br> 
create property Profile.phone embeddedList Phone
 </b>